# Php storm, navigate function in class with contract

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

I did'nt found any method in phpStorm to go to function definition while class I'm using is a contract, and the class i want to go to is bind behind the scenes thru laravel IOC container. How to tell PhpStorm that definition is in other folder? Interface and class implementing interface have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type hinting for PHPStorm this way:

```
/** @var \App\Class\ConcreteObject $object */
$object= App::make(\App\Contracts\SomeContract::class);
```

Now PhpStorm will know `$object` is `\App\Class\ConcreteObject` object and you will be able to see all the methods from this object when using PhpStorm

**EDIT**

Looking at sample from comment you should use:

```
/** @var \proj\Repositories\definitions\UsersRepository $object */ 
$object= App::make(\proj\Repositories\contracts\UsersRepository::class);
$object->saveInfo();
```

to make PhpStorm go to valid `saveInfo` method

Comment: I can see list of methods in class body, but I want to be able to jump to function body in concrete class after ctrl+click

Comment: @Janko You will be able to do this if you use this comment to tell PhpStorm that $object is class of `\App\Class\ConcreteObject`

Comment: /**
         * @var \proj\Repositories\definitions\UsersRepository $object
         */
        $object= App::make(\proj\Repositories\contracts\UsersRepository::class)->saveInfo();  it's not working,  if You could tell me what Im doing wrong? alt+klick wont jump to method source. Klicking on UsersRepository point to contract, not to method definition